# What does the static method wrapper actually do in python?

Tags: python, class, static, wrapper, static-methods

I understand very well the concept of a static method I've used them in other languages, that is not my question. My question is what the staticmethod wrapper itself actually does in python. I've known about static methods for a while in python and I knew you could use the @staticmethod wrapper but do you really need it if your function has at least one argument? I believe it is likely much better practice but what does it actually do? Because if you write a function with the wrapper and then remove the wrapper it still functions exactly the same. I don't think this is intentional I believe it has to do with how instance functions expect self as the first argument and python by default will pass the instance as first argument. If you have at least one argument you pass the function though it appears you don't even need the wrapper so is the wrapper just for when you have no arguments? (I would never actually use this if I make a static method I would use the wrapper for anyone reading the code's sanity just curious though) Here's an example that I would've thought would error, but it doesn't.

(PLEASE NOTE THAT I AM NOT DECLARING AN INSTANCE OF THE CLASS BEFORE CALLING THE NON-STATIC FUNCTION)

```
class Bot1:
    def presentPerson(name):
        print(f"Your name is {name}")

Bot1.presentPerson('name')
```

Comment: the staticmethod decorator only makes a difference if you **do** create an instance.

Comment: Why would you think this would error: `Bot1.presentPerson('name')` what would be the error? `Bot1.presentPerson` is a function that takes one argument, and you pass it an argument...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know, I'm just surprised that you can call an instance method without making an instance of the class. From what I've learned that's not supposed to be possible that's one of the popular reasons for using static methods or class methods

Comment: @Wombatz What? One of the reasons you use the static method decorator is so you don't have to make an instance

Comment: @mizuprogrammer you aren't  calling the method you are just calling the plain function (in your current example). Note, what `@staticmethod` allows you to do is to call `Bot1().presentPerson(name)` or, somewhere else in your class, say an instanve method, do `self.PresentPerson(name)`

Comment: Honestly, I've essentially never used a staticmethod in Python. Some people like it for organizational reasons, but almost always, I just make a module-level function.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I honestly never really use them in python I was just curious as to how it worked as I was surprised you could call an instance method without making an instance

Comment: In Python 3, `SomeClass.some_function` just returns the plain function (Python 2, it would return an "unbound method" object, which would error if you passed the wrong type to the first argument.  In Python 3, it's just the plain function, but if you call it on an instance, `some_instance.some_function` it returns a *bound method object*

Comment: @mizuprogrammer No, the **only** reason to use staticmethod is that you **can** make an instance and still call it (without passing the instance as the first argument). Otherwise you wouldnt need it as you demonstrated.